# Android: How can I use res/integers.xml values in a switch?

Tags: java, android, resources

In my application, I just need some global values with nice names.
First, what I did was putting them all as "public static final" components into a separate class.

Then I realized that what I did with the global Strings (putting them into res/strings.xml and using them by getString(R.string.string_name)) should also work with integers.

However, I first found out that there's no such thing as getInteger(R.integer.integer_name), but only the rather lengthy way:

```
Resources r = getResources();
int integer = getInteger(R.integer.integer_name);
```

Secondly, when I try to use the values in a switch/case expression I only get the message "case expressions must be constant expressions".

So what's the point in using res/integers.xml anyway? I'm just about to put my integers back into some useless class...

Kind regards,
jellyfish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For switch/case expressions we always need constants or enums ( <-- ENUMS!! ) in the case statements. Variables are allowed for the `switch` parameter, but the `case` parameters must never change.

So if you need to "store" the case parameters and like nice names, drop `integers.xml` (doesn't solve your problem) as well as `static final public int`'s - implement an `enum` instead to model your global values.

---

Just waited for some details to propose an enum solution ;) Here we go:

```
public enum Value{ VALUE_ONE(300), VALUE_TWO(501), UNKNOWN(-1);
   private int value;
   private Value(int value) {this.value = value;}

   public int getValue() {
     return value;
   }

   public Value findValue(int value) {
     for (Value v:values()) {
       if (v.value == value)
          return v;
     }
     return Value.UNKNOWN;
}
```

`findValue` can be used to get the enum for a number value, the `UNKNOWN` is an alternative to returning `null` if we look for a unknown number. Have fun :)

Comment: I've thought about enums before, but I think it's kind of not working in my case. I need to be sure that e.g. VALUE_ONE = 300 and VALUE_TWO = 502. Also, I do get integer values (something I can't change) that I have to compare with my constants. The switch/case doesn't seem to allow this (like it would be possible in C/C++). But anyway, the answer that integers.xml doesn't help me atm is answer enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

What have actually done is to create a set of values in either strings.xml or other custom xml files and give them a descriptive names. Those values become static at compile time, every xml value does, and then I can just reference them by their id's.

So in xml I do:

```
<string name="descriptive_name_that_is_easily_read_in_switch_case">
                     What I put here really doesn't matter</string>
```

Then in switch/case

```
switch(someValue){
    case R.id.descriptive_name_that_is_easily_read_in_switch_case:{
      <code>
    }
    break;
}
```

The beauty of this is that I can remove the enum/static initialization away from the code, making it more readable, and still reuse the values all over the program.

Course there are times when you would like your enums/static values only to be visible in a certain class or method. Then this is not what you would do.